# How can I name numerous columns using 'each' function with R?

Tags: r, each

I created a dynamic list using parse and each. I want to add it to my dataframe. Given that this list has a length of 10, I need to create 10 columns names so I can add the elements of my list to the dataframe. Do you know how to name numerous columns in one time ?

I tried to use the command 'names' to create the column names but my dataframe didn't take it into account

```
d %>% update(what=list(p_return_tpL=parse(text="xprev(p_return_t, -1)")))%>%
  update(what=list(lags <- 1:3 %>% each( function(k) parse(text=paste("xprev(eps_t, ", -k, ")")) ) ))

l <- (1:L)%>%each(function(k) parse(text=paste("xprev(eps_t,", -k,")" )))
names(l) <- paste0("dl", 1:L)

dataset <- d %>% update(what=list(p_return_tpL=parse(text="xprev(p_return_t, -1)"), names(l)=l))
```

When I do this I get the error :

```
Error: unexpected '=' in "dataset <- d %>% update(what=list(p_return_tpL=parse(text="xprev(p_return_t, -1)"), names(l)="
```

My sample of data is :

```
> d
       price_t eps_t    p_return_t
1     136.5962     1 -7.615930e-02
2     136.5200    -1  0.000000e+00
3     136.5251     1  0.000000e+00
4     136.5251     1  2.115385e-02
5     136.5960     1  0.000000e+00
6     136.5960     1  2.500000e-04
7     136.5962     1 -7.621599e-02
```

I want it to be

```
> d
       price_t eps_t    p_return_t  eps_t1  eps_t2 
1     136.5962     1 -7.615930e-02    -1      1
2     136.5200    -1  0.000000e+00     1      1
3     136.5251     1  0.000000e+00     1      1
4     136.5251     1  2.115385e-02     1      1
5     136.5960     1  0.000000e+00     1      1
6     136.5960     1  2.500000e-04     1     -1
7     136.5962     1 -7.621599e-02    -1      1
```

I want to add those columns in this data set. I tried many things to assign names to the columns that I created but when I use the command 'names', it names each elements but I cannot use it in the command 'update'. I use 'update' to update my data frame d and add the lists that I created to d

I would be glad if you can give me some hints to resolve this problem

Comment: It's hard to help without a sample of data. Why are you calling `update` on the data frame, when that's meant for updating models AFAIK? And what do you mean by "my dataframe didn't take it into account"? There are a lot of posts on how to assign names—what hasn't worked from any of those others?

Comment: Thank you @camille for your reply. I edited my post with all the info you asked me for.